# Create array from two sets of values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to merge 2 arrays without losing values:

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$b = array('four', 'five', 'six');
```

The result I need is:

```
array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');
```

I know this could be done using a loop + [] operator but it seems like a common task and I'm looking for a simpler solution, maybe using build in array functions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax  : `array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )`

array_merge($a,$b);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_merge(); function like :

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php